# Can Typekit be used in Spotify apps?

Tags: javascript, spotify, typekit

Spotify's Integration Guidelines (casually) mentions that Typekit can be used for introducing web fonts, but their auto-generated documentation makes no mention of what configuration needs to happen. Typekit, out of box, rejects the usual suspects (localhost, 127.0.0.1), and more.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the only way to use a custom typeface in a Spotify app is to use SVG. This is the only way I've been able to make it work. There are tradeoffs, like un-selectable text, that you should be aware of, so I'm not sure there is much upside to this approach.

If you really, really dig through the 'net, you can find a single reference to Spotify's developers removing font rendering capabilities and flagging a future version for re-integration, but that version has come on gone. I'd say it's safe to assume this is not on their radar. I'll avoid speculating what is and is not on their radar, though their developer documentation leaves *much* to be desired.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of your application is `sp://your-app-identifier` I believe. Also, make sure you have the TypeKit domains used for loading their JS etc in the `RequiredPermissions` section of your manifest.

Comment: I have `*.typekit.com/*` in the `RequiredPermissions`, and the JS embed code they provide loads correctly. However, adding `sp://my-app-id` to the Typekit allowed domains and re-publishing my kit does not appear to resolve the issue: the CSS file is still returning a 403.

Comment: You added your actual app ID, right? Not literally `sp://my-app-id`?

Comment: In that case, you should make a simple service to make a request to from the Apps API so you can confirm what the referrer is, then talk to TypeKit about it if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Good idea. I wrote a simple Flask service, which confirms that requests are coming from `127.0.0.1`. How frustrating! I'll get in  touch with Typekit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Carson: did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

Is someone looking at this? There's been no information for months. Not only does TypeKit fail, CSS3 font-face fails and so does Google Web Fonts.